# Animated API's createAnimatedComponent makes FlatList's ref undefined in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-animated, react-native-scrollview

I'm trying to use `scrollToIndex` function of `FlatList` on react-native. However, when I switch the `FlatList` to `createAnimatedComponent(FlatList)`, its `ref` becomes `undefined`.

Is there a way to keep `FlatList`'s `ref` when I use `createAnimatedComponent`?

Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

currently `createAnimatedComponent` exposes a method called `getNode()` that should work for getting the ref to the underlying component.
Here are 2 examples, one with the old refs and one with the new

```
// old ref style
class DemoComp extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // setTimeout is needed for scrollToOffset ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.listRef.getNode().scrollToOffset({ offset: 100, animated: true });
    }, 0);
  }

  render() {
    return <Animated.FlatList ref={r => { this.listRef = r; }} {...otherProps} />;
  }
}

// new ref style
class DemoComp extends Component {
  listRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    // setTimeout is needed for scrollToOffset ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.listRef.current.getNode().scrollToOffset({ offset: 100, animated: true });
    }, 0);
  }

  render() {
    return <Animated.FlatList ref={this.listRef} {...otherProps} />;
  }
}
```

Eventually, in the future `createAnimatedComponent` will switch to "forwarded refs" which will only work with the new style. But that day is a long way away because of all the libraries that depend on the old style.

PS. If you're reading this in the distant future, you can check on the status of forwarded refs in `createAnimatedComponent` here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19650

Comment: It works when `offset` is positive. When it's negative, `scrollToOffset` does not work.